# Select from mysql array of objects with integer number and value null or source to file without duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have a table with rows like number, image. But image is not mandatory, It can be null and when I'm selecting I want to prioritize the row with image over the one with null so i could get clean array with only one row per number.

```
SELECT DISTINCT number, image FROM table ORDER BY number ASC
```

What's now with SELECT DISTINCT:

```
[
    {
        "number": 1,
        "image": null
    },
    {
        "number": 1,
        "image": "https://example.com/image1.png"
    },
    {
        "number": 2,
        "image": null
    },
    {
        "number": 2,
        "image": "https://example.com/image2.png"
    },
    {
        "number": 3,
        "image": "https://example.com/image3.png"
    },
    {
        "number": 3,
        "image": null
    },
    {
        "number": 4,
        "image": null
    }
]
```

What I want to get:

```
[
    {
        "number": 1,
        "image": "https://example.com/image1.png"
    },
    {
        "number": 2,
        "image": "https://example.com/image2.png"
    },
    {
        "number": 3,
        "image": "https://example.com/image3.png"
    },
    {
        "number": 4,
        "image": null
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT number, image FROM table ORDER BY ISNULL(LEFT(image,0));
```

Comment: Still gives both https://imgur.com/a/sLw8sjT even after adding DISTINCT

Comment: @3xanax From the url you provided, it shows that image with datas are up while other without data are down. Was that not what you wanted? Please adjust your `what I want to get`

Comment: I mean, I said "I want to prioritize the row with image over the one with null so I could get clean array with only one row per number." and the "What I want to get" shows that I want one row per number, when row have image then don't select the one with null, so there wont be any duplicates. Maybe I described it wrong in english, it's not my first language so I'm very sorry.